# JanusGraph Transaction and Configuration

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

What is the maximum number of vertex and edge can I make in a single transaction, more over how can I configure JanusGraph server heap to add more memory to it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

For the maximum vertex and edges per transaction it really depends on your system. There was a [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/janusgraph-users/S6tTc9IFZkQ) in the janusgraph-users google group that touched on bulk loading and frequency of committing.

For adding more memory I'm going to steal a tip from the [gremlin console tutorial](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.1-incubating/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/).

> You can change the amount of memory allotted to the console by
>   altering its -Xmx setting in bin/gremlin.sh. This setting controls the
>   maximum size of the JVM memory allocation pool. To set this value to
>   1024 megabytes, you would set this value as follows: -Xmx1024m. It is
>   likely best to append this setting to the initialization of the
>   JAVA_OPTIONS variable in that script. If you choose to override
>   JAVA_OPTIONS, be sure to examine the default settings in
>   bin/gremlin.sh to include them as they should not be omitted in your
>   override.

If you need to add more memory to the server you'd also allocate more memory with -Xmx, but in gremin-server.sh or janusgraph.sh instead, depending on whichever you're running your server with.

Also I have some coworkers that did some research on bulk loading performance and you might find their [presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/ChinHuang4/onboarding-with-janusgraph-performance) helpful.